# How do I purchase DLC for Bioware games? Through Origin or Bioware?

Tags: origin

I am fairly new to using Origin. I was planning on purchasing the following games:

1. Mass Effect trilogy
2. Mass Effect 3 digital deluxe upgrade edition
3. Dragon Age Ultimate
4. Dragon Age 2.

I know not all the Mass Effect 3 DLC nor the Dragon Age 2 ALC is available there.

My questions are:

1. If I purchase all the games above, can I purchase the DLC from Origin? Or do I go through Bioware?
2. If I buy the extra DLC, does it get installed through the Origin client once I decide to install the base games?
3. If I purchase everything before running the install and play, will the Origin client automatically install the DLC if it has to be bought via Bioware?

Comment: @Close Voters - this isn't off-topic, It is neither a shopping recommendation nor is it asking for an itemised list [as defined in our FAQ](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/1617/28182). It is also not 'Too Broad' - It is a question about how some of Origin's features work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While viewing any game with DLC in origin, there will be a letter 'i' which brings up an information popup containing add-ons, which will then display all available DLC. From here you can buy and download it all provided you already own the game.

Note specifically for Mass Effect: Bring Down The Sky, this is not available on Origin and but [EA have provided it as a free download](http://help.ea.com/en/article/mass-effect-bring-down-the-sky-dlc-redemption/). Pinnacle station is available on Origin (although I'd personally give it a skip as it doesn't really add anything).

Comment: I notice that Bring down the sky and pinnacle station comes with the trilogy